# giving exception in WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); await Firebase.initializeApp();

Tags: flutter, firebase

I have used

```
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

in main function it is giving exception while debugging and emulator displays blank screen when it is runned without debugging

It is showing following exception ->
Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null))

I have updated dependencies, also added firebase core and also updated it please help me in this problem

[IMAGE OF MY CODE WHERE IT IS SHOWING ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EZak.jpg)

output of pub outdated

````
[*] indicates versions that are not the latest available.

Package Name              Current   Upgradable  Resolvable  Latest   

direct dependencies: all up-to-date.

dev_dependencies: all up-to-date.

transitive dependencies:
string_scanner            *1.1.0    *1.1.0      *1.1.0      1.2.0
term_glyph                *1.2.0    *1.2.0      *1.2.0      1.2.1
test_api                  *0.4.9    *0.4.9      *0.4.9      0.4.17
vector_math               *2.1.2    *2.1.2      *2.1.2      2.1.4
all dependencies are up-to-date.```
````

Comment: did you try with flutterfire CLI it might be a problem with old dependencies because the latest updated firebase uses CLI.

Comment: Yes I have used flutterfire cli . How to update it?

Comment: I have added image of my error please check

Comment: well i had the same problem when trying to hot restart the app after adding firebase. im suggesting to do clean build

Answer (score 1):

Check your Firebase SDK dependencies in Project build.gradle file and Application build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
  }
  dependencies {
    ...
    // Add this line
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
  }
}

allprojects {
  ...
  repositories {
    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
    ...
  }
}
```

And in your app level build.grandle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// Add this line
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {
  // Import the Firebase BoM
  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.2.0')

  // Add the dependency for the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
  // When using the BoM, don't specify versions in Firebase dependencies
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

  // Add the dependencies for any other desired Firebase products
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries
}
```

Comment: Added dependencies but still problem is not solved

Answer (score 0):

Did you also run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` again?

Otherwise can you run `flutter pub outdated` ans share the output?

Comment: Yes I have used it but still it is showing that exception

Comment: I have added image of my error please check

Comment: shared the output of pub outdated please check

Answer (score 0):

1.Add to pubspec.yaml

```
firebase_core :
```

2.Add to main.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();
runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Already added it

Comment: Help me out with your code snippet

Comment: I have added image of my error please check

Comment: Do you run it on a Android or Ios ?

Comment: Remove async keyword from main method

Comment: I am running it on android emulator